# Is there a way to display the outdated dependencies from a requirements.txt in a Github wiki?

Tags: github, pip, github-pages, gollum-wiki

I have a Github wiki that I am maintaining and I want to include a section that displays whether or not the python dependancies within requirements.txt are outdated. I know how to do this manually using:

```
pip list --outdated
```

What is the easiest way that I can dynamically have that called whenever the page is accessed? or another method that gives the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "whenever the page is accessed"

I am not aware of a webhook trigger by accessing the page: that would be costly whenever a lot of people want to read said page.

But since a [GitHub wiki is a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/), it should be possible, as a [pre-push commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_other_client_hooks) to trigger a local command `pip list --outdated` and modify the wiki locally cloned repo in order to push that output to the wiki, before finally pushing your commit on your regular repo.